# How Can I pass a PHP array to a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, php

I have an array which have some values stored in it but I want to transfer the elements of that array into javascript array for further processing. How can I do so?

Comment: Take a look at "json_encode"

Answer (score 2):

You can encode your variable to json using `json_encode($php_array)`. 
Then on JavaScript side, parse it back using `JSON.parse()`

```
<script>
    var foo = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: No reason to parse it in JavaScript. JSON is already valid JavaScript. This just opens the door for injections. `let foo = <?= json_encode($array) ?>;`

Comment: Yes, it is! Answer is updated.